# Where does automatic mount get the username?

Tags: 18.04, mount, automount

It seems that removable media gets (by `pmount`?) mount under `/media/[username]/`.

How is that username resolved? What if many users are logged in? What if no users are logged in? What if I just SSH to the machine? How can I know under which user the media gets mounted?